# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Core_prices' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

i use a function calculate servers prices so i made a function which retrieve a defalut prices of a server components and calculate server price for each server exsit in my DB but i try to run this function, i get this error:

```
function.py

import MySQLdb

def calculations_metric (param) :
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "aqw", "PFE_Project")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM examples_calculationsmetric"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        RAM_prices = int(row[1])
        Core_prices = int(row[2])
        HHD_SATA_prices =int(row[3])
        HHD_SSD_prices =int(row[4])
        CPU_priority = int(row[5])
        Avaibility = int(row[6])
    db.close()

    db1 = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "aqw", "PFE_Project")
    cursor1 = db1.cursor()
    sql1 = "SELECT * FROM examples_servercomponents WHERE id ='%d'" %(param)
    cursor1.execute(sql1)
    results1 = cursor1.fetchall()
    for row in results1:
        if row[6] == 'SATA':
            Core_price = int(row[2]) * Core_prices # the error is here
            Priority_price = int(row[3]) * CPU_priority
            RAM_price = int(row[4]) * RAM_prices
            HDD_price = int(row[5]) * HHD_SATA_prices
            Availibility_price = int(row[7])*Avaibility

        elif row[6] == 'SSD':
            Core_price = int(row[2]) * Core_prices
            Priority_price = int(row[3]) * CPU_priority
            RAM_price = int(row[4]) * RAM_prices
            HDD_price = int(row[5]) * HHD_SSD_prices
            Availibility_price = int(row[7])*Avaibility

    price = Core_price + Priority_price + RAM_price + HDD_price + Availibility_price
    db1.close()
    return price
```

i don't get what is the error so if can anyone help i will be so greatful

Comment: Why are you connecting to the same database twice, as a matter of interest? Why not just *reuse* the first connection for the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `SELECT * FROM examples_calculationsmetric` doesn't return any results, `Core_prices` is never set (nor are the other variables in that loop).

Python names do not exist until assigned to, so if `results` is an empty list, the names inside the `for` loop never get assigned to and thus do *not* exist by the time you loop over `results1` later on.

You could set default values for those names as a work-around:

```
RAM_prices = 0
Core_prices = 0
HHD_SATA_prices = 0
HHD_SSD_prices = 0
CPU_priority = 0
Avaibility = 0
```

to at least ensure that they are defined.

Comment: the error was because examples_calculationsmetric Table was empty. there is no line in that table.
it works now